# Integrating composer with codeigniter to autoload CSS and JS

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php

I have composer set up in CodeIgniter 3, it is fully set up and I have installed bootstrap and font-awesome in the vendor folder. How do these then get included in my view files?

AutoLoad.php exists and I have set composer_autoload to true in config.

I was expecting bootstrap and font awesome to be automatically loaded in my HTML head. Is this correct?

Comment: Composer is meant for managing your server-side (PHP-) dependencies, not your frontend dependencies and assets. You should consider a different tool. For example the vendor/ folder should not be public, so installing bootstrap there does not make much sense. Maybe use something like gulp or webpack for managing css & js instead.

Comment: Composer will never modify files. So it won't add your assets automatically (although wouldn't that be nice). To echo what @dbrumann said, you should consider a different tool and take in to account that anything in the `application` or `vendor` directory should be shielded from public view with htaccess deny from all. All your public assets should go elsewhere - typically root or `root/public`.